H-infinity gain of a parameterized MIMO transfer function
Consider a multi-input-multi-output linear system $\dot{x} = A_{\mu}x + u$, such that

$\mu \in [0, \mu^{\star})$ is a small parameter,
$A_{\mu} \triangleq A_0 + B_0 K_{\mu}$, where $A_0$ has eigenvalues $\pm j\omega_k$ for $k \in \{0,1,\dots,K\}$ and $\omega_k \geq 0$ are known. The eigenvalues $\pm j\omega_k$ have multiplicity possibly greater than 1.
$A_{\mu}$ has eigenvalues $-c_k\mu \pm j\omega_k$, achieved by designing the gain $K_{\mu}$ to shift the eigenvalues of $A_0$ left by some small (and known) amount $c_k\mu > 0$. (I need the stabilizability of $(A_0, B_0)$, of course).

I want to calculate the $H_{\infty}$ gain of the transfer function (or transfer matrix) from $u$ to $x$ denoted by $G(s) = (sI_n - A_{\mu})^{-1}$, which is $\sup_{\omega \in \mathbb{R}} \sigma_{\max} \left(G(j\omega)\right)$, i.e., the supremum over all largest singular value of $G(j \omega)$.
For a SISO system, this is pretty simple: let's say $A_{\mu} = -\mu$, then $G(s) = \frac{1}{s + \mu}$ and $\Vert G(s) \Vert_{H_{\infty}} = \sup_{\omega \in \mathbb{R}} \sigma_{\max} \left(\frac{1}{j\omega + \mu}\right) = \sup_{\omega \in \mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\omega^2 + \mu^2}} = \frac{1}{\mu}$.
However, I'm not sure how to do this in the general MIMO case above, since without assuming any normality of $A_{\mu}$ I don't really see how the eigenvalue information can be easily used. I am happy to include my latest attempt if needed, however, it isn't exactly going anywhere. Any suggestions or hints would be greatly appreciated!

In MIMO case eigenvalues say nothing about $H_\infty$ norm of the system. In general, this calculation is done numerically. Either finding the maximum of $\sigma_\max G(j \omega)$ or using LMI techniques.

@obareey or solving a Riccati equation or through the computation of the spectrum of the Hamiltonian matrix.

I see, that's what I feared was the case. Thanks regardless!
